# No USB devices or running emulators detected in IntelliJ

Tags: android, debugging, intellij-idea, usb, adb

I have clicked on my Samsung Galaxy build number seven times and got a message, that I am a developer now. I connected this device to my computer via USB. I have installed Android SDK and created a sample project in `IntelliJ`.

But when I try to run it, the following window appears:

[image]

`Troubleshoot` link does not work.

What else was I to do in order to be able to run Android programs from IntelliJ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to enable **USB debugging** in developer options. Like on image below

[image]